# Move items from one list to another

Tags: c#

I have a list which contains objects of type Student with properties like name,surname,id,year etc. What I want is that I remove a particular student from a list with a specific index and throw it in another list. Is there a way of doing so?
For example:

```
        if (((mystudent[index].Year== 7)) {
              mystudent.RemoveAt(index);
           // now how I shall throw the Student to a new list
}
```

Thanks for your info. My problem now is that I have 2 lists in seperate classes. When I remove an item from a list its working but when I want to view the added item to the list from the other class I'm not getting the item.

```
public class SeniorStudentsClass
    {
        public List<Student> studlist = new List<Student>();

public void ViewStudents()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < studlist.Count; i++)
            {               
                Console.Write(studlist[i].Id + "\t");
                Console.Write(studlist[i].Year + "\t");
                Console.Write(studlist[i].Name + "\t");
                Console.Write(studlist[i].Surname + "\t");
                Console.Write(studlist[i].DOB + "\t");
                Console.Write(studlist[i].Addr);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

  public class JuniorStudentsClass
    {
       public List<Student> mystudent = new List<Student>();  
       SeniorStudentsClass sc = new SeniorStudentsClass();

        public void PromoteStudents(int index)
        {
            SearchItem(index);
            Console.WriteLine("current record:");
            Console.WriteLine("id is:" + mystudent[index].Id);
            Console.WriteLine("year is:" + mystudent[index].Year);
            Console.WriteLine("name is:" + mystudent[index].Name);
            Console.WriteLine("surname is:" + mystudent[index].Surname);
            Console.WriteLine("dob is:" + mystudent[index].DOB);
            Console.WriteLine("address is:" + mystudent[index].Addr);
            Console.WriteLine("year is:"+mystudent[index].Year);
            if (((mystudent[index].Year== 7)) || ((mystudent[index].Year == 8)))
            {
                var student = mystudent[index];
                mystudent.RemoveAt(index);
                sc.studlist.Add(student);
                Console.WriteLine("student promoted to senior student");

        }
```

Comment: TIP:  You will want to copy it before you dispose of it.

Comment: Simply copy the object from one list to the other, before you delete it. With something like: SecondList[i] = FirstList[i];

Answer (score 6):

Linq will make it easier.

```
var moveables = mystudent.Where(x => x.Year == 7);

list2.AddRage(moveables);

mystudent.RemoveRange(moveables);
```

If the "another list" doesn't exist yet, You can even simplify making it in just two lines of code:

```
var list2 = mystudent.Where(x => x.Year == 7).ToList();

mystudent.RemoveRange(list2);
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
if (mystudent[index].Year == 7) 
{
    var studentToRemove = mystudent[index]; //get a reference to the student
    mystudent.RemoveAt(index); //Remove
    otherList.Add(studentToRemove); //Put student on another list
}
```

Assuming you're loping through a lot of students - and trying to move all the ones with a specific year - something like this may be better:

```
var yearSevenStudents = mystudent.Where(student => student.Year == 7).ToList();
```

Answer (score -3):

I hope this will answer your question since I don't really understand it, but try copying the student to a new table and then delete the old one

Comment: I guess that he knew this already.
He was imho asking for the code to do this.

Comment: Can someone help me in answering the question because I edited it